# Create XML file with <text>

Tags: xml

I have a file that I need to convert to XML, but the file has some text that has `<foobar>` that is part of an element. I can generate the XML, but then when it's parsed by another program the parsing is not done correctly.

For example, I end up with a XML file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<log>
   <file-tag>20141027-15:46:11/getDipCAs.log</file-tag>
   <log-begin>Logging started</log-begin>
   <log-entry>File "/home/ti-us-dev/releases/current-linux/bin/getDipCAs", line 2211, in <module> </log-entry>
   <log-end>Logging terminated</log-end>
</log>
```

The `<module>` messes up the later parsing. Is there some way I can escape this in the XML file or handle it when it's being parsed?

Comment: the answer is probably "Generate the XML with an XML library instead of mashing strings together", but you haven't shown us how you are generating the XML.

Comment: It's being done in python 'manually'. I don't know why it's being done that way. I didn't write the program (and would never have written it that way myself), and I don't want to (nor am I being paid to) make wholesale changes to the program. I've just been asked to fix this one thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change those characters:

```
"   &quot;
'   &apos;
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
&   &amp;
```

in php, str_replace() should do the job quite easy

Answer (score -1):

You have to use &lt instead of < and &gt instead of > around module(followed by ; ).